# Finding the difference in dates in a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have the following columns in a table in our database here is an example.....

```
Transaction_Date | Trans_Code

1/1/2015         | JR
1/15/2015        | CP01
```

So I am trying to find the difference between the invoice date (JR) and the payment date (CP01). What is the best way to go about this? I tried to do a sub select but that didn't work.

Here is something else I tried with the below suggestion

```
Select

INVC_NUMB,
CUST_NUMB,
DATEDIFF (
    DAY,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TRANS_CODE = 'JR' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, TRANS_RDAT +5843, 0), 101) END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN TRANS_CODE = 'CP01' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, TRANS_RDAT +5843, 0), 101) END)
) AS DAYDIFF



FROM AR20

WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, TRANS_RDAT +5843, 0), 112) > 20141231

GROUP BY
INVC_NUMB,
CUST_NUMB,
CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, TRANS_RDAT +5843, 0), 1)

ORDER BY 
CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, TRANS_RDAT +5843, 0), 1)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What result have you got and what is expected result?

Comment: How are they related at all? I'm missing a value which both records share like a `Transaction_Id`.

Comment: On SQL server you can use the DATEDIFF function to get the difference between two dates. How to get the dates depends on the structure of your data. Like Tim Schmelter said, it seems you are missing the field that will link the two records together.

Comment: First, don't store date as varchar... You can use datediff(day, firstdate, lastdate). day can be replaced by whatever you need (minute, second, ...)

Comment: There are a few fields that both records share specifically invoice number and cust numb @TimSchmelter

Comment: I tried to use a select subquery if that's the right term.

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select datediff(day,
                max(case when trans_code = 'JR' then transaction_date end),
                max(case when trans_code = 'CP01' then transaction_date end)
               ) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: Why use Max? Wouldn't just pull the difference of those numbers anyway without looking for the largest number?

Comment: If there are only two numbers rows, then the `max()` is simply choosing the appropriately value.  You need to do aggregation to get the values in one row so you can do arithmetic.